# Cannot get Entity out of Datastore Key

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm using a [GAE Object mapping framework](http://bit.ly/1yaiWkc) (and built our app around it) with this code working

```
Key key = put(thing);
Thing thing = get(Thing.class, key);
```

That code above works great.

Now, there is this `putInTransaction` method:

```
@Override
public Key putInTransaction(Object object) {
    Transaction tx = _ds.beginTransaction(_options);
    Key result = null;
    try {
        result = put(object);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        tx.rollback();
    } finally {
        if (tx.isActive()) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Which I compared the key from the `put(thing)` and `putInTransaction(thing)` code and its having the same datastore `Key` with the same `kind`, `id`, `name` and `appIdNamespace`

The problem now is when the key is used to `get(Thing.class,key)` when doing JUnit test on the `putInTranscation(thing)` it does not return the entity while when testing with the `put(thing)` it works fine. **What could be wrong here?**

Comment: I don't see you commit the transaction anywhere ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that there's a missing Datastore Transaction commit in the code that needed to be added.